# Why am I getting this error when trying to connect to my WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-services

```
The caller was not authenticated by the service.
```

I have a WCF service hosted in a windows service on one machine and I have another windows service on a different machine as a client connecting to the WCF service on the first machine.    I'm guessing it has something to do with security, but I'm not sure what to do.  Here is the app.config of the client:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsDualHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSDualHttpBinding_IWCFService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" 
                     openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" 
                     bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" 
                     maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" 
                     messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" 
                              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"/>
                <security mode="Message">
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" 
                             algorithmSuite="Default"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsDualHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/WCF/WCFService/" 
                  binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSDualHttpBinding_IWCFService" 
                  contract="WCFService.IWCFService" name="WSDualHttpBinding_IWCFService">
            <identity>
                <dns value="localhost"/>
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

And the app.config of the service:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="WCF.WCFService" behaviorConfiguration="WCFBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" contract="WCF.IWCFService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint
      address="mex"
      binding="mexHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration=""
      contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/WCF/WCFService/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WCFBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

What do I need to do to be able to connect to my WCF service.

One other thing to note is I created a simple console app as a client to the wcf service and it is able to connect to the service without a problem and the app.config file looks identical.  Maybe is has something to do with the client service running as a different user?  I am ok with removing any and all security, but don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

The Console application is probably running with your credentials, the Windows Service that cannot connect with the wcf service is probably running with the local system account. Try installing the service with authentication mode "user" and your credentials

Comment: don't do this - you can allways overwrite the installed service with other account infos but putting your credentials into a textfile might not be the best idea!

Comment: and hilarious when the staff member leaves the company and his account is deactivated

Comment: It was meant as a test to determine the source of the problem

Answer (score 0):

two things: check the identity above and make sure that your other service is running not as a local-user (default! for example NetworkService) but as a domain user or rethink your settings (you can TEST this by running the service under your account if you got the needed rights in your domain)